# Modify a JSON File in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, coffeescript

I'm not sure how I can modify JSON file format with coffee script
I have something like this

```
{"counts":{"USA":100,"France":90,"Italy":80,"Canada":70,"Germany":60}}
```

I want to convert the json to this

```
[{text: "USA", weight: 100},{text: "France", weight: 90},{text: "Italy",weight: 80},{text: "Canada", weight: 70}, {text: "Germany", weight: 60}]
```

This would be pretty easy in Java, but not sure about coffee script

Comment: What is tripping you up?

Comment: You cannot modify files with JavaScript running in the browser.

Comment: just started using coffee script yesterday so don't know how to use it yet

Comment: How would you do it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoffeeScript features I would use:

- Array comprehensions (return value of for loop)
- `for key, value of object` loop
- object literal comisition shorthard `{ foo }` same as `{ foo: foo }`

Example:

```
data = {"counts":{"USA":100,"France":90,"Italy":80,"Canada":70,"Germany":60}}

result =
  for text, weight of data.counts
    { text, weight }

console.log result
# [{"text":"USA","weight":100},{"text":"France","weight":90},{"text":"Italy","weight":80},{"text":"Canada","weight":70},{"text":"Germany","weight":60}]
```

Comment: sweet, thanks! so data.counts accesses the inner section by name? so if i had multiple sections like the counts i could just access them with data.(section name)?
very helpful answer thanks

Comment: Yep. But if I may, you should take a step back form coffee script and learn JavaScript.  CoffeeScript is simply JavaScript with syntax sugar.  And there are more resources out there about JavaScript, so I'd highly recommend starting there and learning CoffeeScript later.

Comment: well i'm doing something i don't normally do on a system that uses coffeescript, i do want to learn javascript but this system is built on coffeescript (using javascript would break convention)

Comment: @Lemonio: Note that this has nothing to do with JSON. `data` here is an object of objects which is converted to an array of objects. Those are data types/structures in JavaScript. JSON is a textual data-exchange format. They look similar, but they are completely different things.

Comment: actually that's giving me an unexpected CALL_START? Are you sure that's how I do the indentation?

Comment: @Lemonio [works for me...](http://coffeescript.org/#try:data%20%3D%20%7B%22counts%22%3A%7B%22USA%22%3A100%2C%22France%22%3A90%2C%22Italy%22%3A80%2C%22Canada%22%3A70%2C%22Germany%22%3A60%7D%7D%0A%0Aresult%20%3D%0A%20%20for%20text%2C%20weight%20of%20data.counts%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20text%2C%20weight%20%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log%20result)

Comment: yeah sorry looks like i had the format wrong, its initially in that format, but then it actually changes to this format [{label: "USA", count: 100},{label:"France",count:90} etc...
so I think I would parse it like this?

Comment: result = for data.label,data.count of data {text,weight}?

Comment: the slight difference here is that the stuff already has labels i just need a different label